# Get sibling element from PrimeFaces datatable row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable created in PrimeFaces which receives and render a list of objects. At the end of the row I have a commandButton element and when it is used it do some stuff on the managedBean on the server.

All the data about the current row is retrieved using an object id placed in the command button in the param attribute.

The problem is that I have a selectOneMenu element and it is not related to the object. I select one value that affects the logic behind.

Here is the table:

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" bgcolor="#cce4ff"
                     cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" rendered="#{indexBean.showChannelList}"
                     style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 100px;">
            <p:dataTable var="program" value="#{indexBean.programList}" style="width:1000px;"
                         paginator="True" rows="10" rowIndexVar="row" sortBy="#{program.id}"
                         paginatorPosition="bottom" widgetVar="programDT" id="programDT">
```

... That the select

```
<p:column headerText="text" width="15%">
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="select-valability" value="#{indexBean.valabilitySelected}" disabled="#{indexBean.disabled}" style="font-size: small;">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{indexBean.listValabilities}" />
                        <f:param value="#{program.id}" />
                        <f:ajax resetValues="true" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>
```

... and there is the command button

```
<p:column headerText="text" width="20%" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h:commandButton id="cmd-button-id" value="gen JSON" action="#{indexBean.action}" 
                                     style="width: 200px; height: 30px;"
                                     class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"
                                     >
                        <f:param name="programId" value="#{program.id}" />

                    </h:commandButton>
                </p:column>
```

I want to be able to get the value of the select element from that specific row from which the action was triggered.

I've try with `context.findComponent()` but it gives me null even if I put the absolute path to the element with the index generated by JSF table as `form:table:index:staticIdOfSelect`.

I don't know how to get the sibling element. That was another though.

From the bean class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class IndexBean
```

I'm really stuck here.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some element on the row to set an ajax listener in the bean to store the data and then update="the element" you want to get the information from.

Comment: Please improve this 'answer' or make it into a comment

Comment: Can you be more specific? An example maybe? I had an ajax listener on the command button and I thought that I could easily get the parent, i.e. the row element and than get the only SelectOneMenu element from that row's choldren. But apparently the parent isn't a <tr> element is the column and I'm stuck again.

Comment: You have what you need. But I think you are going about it the wrong way looking for the parent inside the datatable. You should get it from the java code where you have all the information.

Comment: I've resolved the problem using a transient field in the model and than f:setPropertyActionListener and than the target was set to an object on the server of required type. Thanks for the hint.